# A merge / concat like method for javascript objects.. not extend

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

I would like to join nested objects with similar keys:

```
var obj1 = {
  id: 1,
  styles: {
    background: "white"
  }
};

var obj2 = {
  id: 2,
  styles: {
    border: "1px solid #ccc"
  }
};

var merged = merge(obj1, obj2);

// desired outcome
merged = {
  id: 2,
  styles: {
    background: "white",
    border: "1px solid #ccc"
  }
}
```

jQuery's extend method and similar ones that I've seen never concat Object properties, which is excactly what I'm looking for. Other than building this method myself, I'm hoping and quite sure there's already a solution for this..

Comment: What you just described is exactly what jQuery.extend does in deep copy mode. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend

Comment: Click run code snippet in my answer and watch console. How is my result different from your desired outcome?

Comment: your jsbin has an extra line. `var obj2 = {}`

Answer (score 1):

jQuery.extend does what you want.

```js
var obj1 = {
  id: 1,
  styles: {
    background: "white"
  }
};

var obj2 = {
  id: 2,
  styles: {
    border: "1px solid #ccc"
  }
};

var merged = jQuery.extend(true, obj1, obj2);

// desired outcome
console.log(merged);
console.log({
  id: 2,
  styles: {
    background: "white",
    border: "1px solid #ccc"
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Perfect, not sure how I missed that. I don't want to import all of jQuery just for this method though.. Other than browsing the source code, know of any gists for this?

Comment: https://github.com/mout/mout/blob/v0.1.0/src/object/deepFillIn.js Think this should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple method that I wrote up which does the trick nicely and doesn't require you to import a huge library just for this functionality.

```
function extend(obj /* , ...source */) {
    for (var i = 1; i < arguments.length; i++) {
      for (var key in arguments[i]) {
        if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(arguments[i], key)) {
          obj[key] = (typeof arguments[i][key] === 'object' ? extend(obj[key], arguments[i][key]) : arguments[i][key]);
        }
      }
    }
    return obj;
  }
```